# Delegate Access to sub folders in Outlook

Tags: exchange, outlook

Is there a way to access the whole mailbox (including all sub folders) with Delegated Access without having to set permission on each folder?

Outlook version: 2007,
Exchange server: 2003

And can this be done without having to do it from the users (the one delegating) Outlook?

/Markus

Answer (score 3):

Within Outlook I usually go to Tools-->Options-->Delegates and add whomever you want.  There you can set someone to have access to the entire Inbox, Calendar, Tasks, etc. without having to configure each folder individually

Though I don't know how to do that server side.  I've always done it on the one delegating the permissions.

Comment: Good tip!  And if the admin has mailbox rights (I know, bad admin, no best-practices-donut) they *can* indeed do this without user intervention (though from their own Outlook, rather than server-side).

Comment: Yes, this is what I did, but even though I set full access to the mailbox the user is still not seeing the full mailbox. (This after having added the mailbox in her owns Outlook.)

Answer (score 2):

In Active Directory Users and Computers go into the users properties that has the mailbox that you want to grant access to. This should be on a server or pc that also has the Exhange 2003 tools installed.

Click on the Exchange Advanced Tab, and click the Mailbox Rights button.
Click the Add button and choose the user who you want to be able to access the mailbox, and click OK.
Back on the permissions page highlight the user you just added and below tick the Allow column for 'Full mailbox access'.
Click Apply and Ok.

Back on outlook of the person who needs to be able to access the mailbox, goto the Tools menu then Account settings.
On the E-mail tab highlight the Microsoft Exchange account and click the Change button above.
Click the More settings button, and then the Advancded tab.
Click on the Add button and type the name of the users mailbox to be accessed and click OK.
More than one mailbox can be added here. If so repeat the previous steps.
Click OK, then Cancel, and Close.

You will be prompted to restart Outlook.

Comment: Which Exchange 2003 tool do I need to have installed?

Answer (score 1):

[PFDavAdmin](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=635BE792-D8AD-49E3-ADA4-E2422C0AB424&displaylang=en) will do this from the server, or your workstation.  You can choose any level in the mailbox tree and propagate the permission's down the tree.  You do not need to visit the workstation for the changes to take effect.

I am guessing you want to add permission's to the folders for a user and not creating a delegate for another user.